# Dropbox takes hours to sync & shows different modified times (coincidentially in the future)

Tags: sync, dropbox, date-modified

Dropbox is taking hours to synchronize. I can't tell exactly how long because the time stamps on the website make no sense - they say the files were modified tomorrow. My netbook (Windows XP) says they're last modified tomorrow in Windows Explorer as well.

The time and date on both computers are correct.

The files in question are in a symlinked directory on the laptop and they are synchronized fine with the correct timestamps.

I have looked for an option to force Dropbox to sync, but haven't located one. There might be a command line method, but I haven't had the time to explore.

Comment: Be sure not to exceed 87 MPH in your car.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of sounding like a broken record: Have you tried restarting it?
My dropbox has sync issues all the time -- but only the installation on my netbook.
"Stop Dropbox" and then starting it again it usually syncs quite nicely afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, and shutting down Dropbox and restarting it (the program, not the computer) worked great.  It completed the sync in less than a minute after trying to sync for the previous 24 hours.

To shutdown Dropbox, just click on the tray icon and select "Exit."  Then restart it by finding the program in your start menu/All-programs.